# Probability of a specific hand in Yahtzee

Tags: probability

Suppose we are playing Yahtzee and I want to know what the odds of rolling a small straight on the first roll is. I would like to compute the probability of rolling any combination of 5 dice where 4 of the dice could be arranged to form a linear sequence with a common difference of ±1 (e.g. 1,2,3,4 or 2,3,4,5 or 6,5,4,3).

My thinking is this:

The size of the sample space, $S$, for any roll of all 5 dice is $|S| = 6^5$.

There are $\binom{5}{4}$ ways to select the dice which may form our sequence.

From these subsets of dice, there is $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to select the which die will be the start of my sequence, $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to select which die will be the second, $\binom{2}{1}$ way to select which die will be third and only 1 way to select which die will be the end of the sequence.

To count the number of combinations that form small straights with exactly 4 dice I used $R$: $$R = \{(1,2,3,4,x), (2,3,4,5,y), (3,4,5,6,z): x,y,z \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}, x \notin \{5\}, y \notin \{1,6\}, z\notin \{2\}\} \implies |R| = 14$$

Therefore the probability of rolling a small straight, $P(A)$, is $$P(A) = \frac{14\binom{5}{4}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{6^5} = \frac{14 \cdot 5!}{6^5}$$

This does not appear to be correct. What have I missed or defined incorrectly?

Comment: Counting the small straights seems harder than you are suggesting.  First of all, I assume you are explicitly excluding large straights?  Either way, you should clarify.   Then, you also have to distinguish between cases with a double, like $(1,2,3,4,4)$ and cases without a double like $(1,2,3,4,6)$.

Comment: With the dice results being $1,2,4,3,1$... which small straight is this?  Have you double counted some outcomes perhaps?  Once with $(1,2,4,3),1$ and again with $1,(2,4,3,1)$?